# How can we filter text from array

Tags: asp.net

**I have an array which return data in size like 3,6,9,12,15.. (multiplication of 3)**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string GridData = ViewState["ShowItem"].ToString();
string[] FilterData = GridData.Split('^');
```

Above array return data like..

```
FilterData [0] = "Pizza";     (Item)
FilterData [1] = "2$";        (Price)
FilterData [2] = "2";         (Quantity)
FilterData [3] = "Burger";
FilterData [4] = "5$";
FilterData [5] = "1";
FilterData [6] = "Cesa";
FilterData [7] = "7$";
FilterData [8] = "3";

now I want to enter above data as column wise in database like: 
Item      Price    Quantity    Total(Price*Quantity)
```

**now I want to run a loop that add data of particular field like:**

```
for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < FilterData.Length; nIndex++)
{
DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
drow["ProductItem"] = FilterData[nIndex].ToString();   (Add all Item)
drow["Cost"] = FilterData[nIndex].ToString();          (Add all Cost)
drow["Quantity"] = FilterData[nIndex].ToString();       (Add all Quantity)
double Total= Convert.ToDouble(FilterData[nIndex].ToString()) * Convert.ToInt32(FilterData[nIndex].ToString());       (Add all cost*Quantity)
                drow["Total"] = Total;
dt.Rows.Add(drow);
```

}

**So can anybody help me how could I run the loop so it add data to particular column like:**
    Item   Price   Quantity  Total(Price*Quantity)

```
Pizza    2       2             4
Burger   5       1             5
Cesa     7       3             21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment `nIndex` by 3 each time, access each member by it's offset from `nIndex`:

```
for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < FilterData.Length; nIndex += 3)
{
    DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
    drow["ProductItem"] = FilterData[nIndex];               // Item
    var cost = FilterData[nIndex + 1];                      // Cost
    var qty = FilterData[nIndex + 2];                       // Quantity
    drow["Cost"] = cost;
    drow["Quantity"] = qty;
    double Total = 
        Convert.ToDouble(cost.Remove(cost.Length - 1)) *    // remove $
        Convert.ToInt32(qty);                               // Total
    drow["Total"] = Total;
    dt.Rows.Add(drow);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful my dear ! it works fine. Thanks a lot for short logic & it reduces my number of line code. Thanks :)

Comment: Smart Answer p.s.w.g !